# Where/How to define the structure of the output xml in spring batch

Tags: xml, xsd, spring-batch

I have multiple xmls from which I generated multiple java classes. I want to generate one unique xml with a particular content. Where/How can I define the structure of the wanted output xml by spring batch?

Here is my configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
<import resource="../config/context.xml" />
<batch:job id="bghJob" parent="simpleJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="xmlItemWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:xmls/*.xml" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="xmlItemReader" />
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="invoiceUnMarshaller" />
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="T_Document" />
</bean>

<bean id="invoiceUnMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.xxx.generatedByJaxb" />
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/Facture.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="invoiceMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="Facture" />
</bean>

<bean id="invoiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx.model.output.Facture</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please notice that when I generate my XML file it's almost empty. I contains the following: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Facture></Facture>

Comment: Am I missing something ? maybe in the marshaller or unmarshaller ?